# How can I interact with a website through Racket

Tags: racket

I am currently getting data off of some websites for my programs in Racket but how can I use Racket to interact with a website in order to log in and download a file or perform some kind of action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the `net` library. Exactly how to log into the a particular web-site depends on how it is written. You need to look at the html to find out what the fields are called.

Look at the bottom of this page to see an example of how to login to a web-page.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/http-client.html?q=url